# React Native tab view lazy is not loading last scene

Tags: react-native

Here is my tabview:

```
 <TabView
            navigationState={{index, routes}}
            renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
            renderScene={renderScene}
            initialLayout={{width: layout.width}}
            onIndexChange={() => {}}
            lazy
          />

 const renderScene =({route})=>{
    if (route.key == 'first') {
      return <FirstRoute />;
    }
    if (route.key == 'second') {
      return <SecondRoute />;
    }
    if (route.key == 'third') {
      return <ThirdRoute />;
    }
  }

 const FirstRoute = () => (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      {visible == true ? (
        <RenderNoContent />
      ) : (
        <CustomerDetails
          walletDataList={walletDataList}
          customerData={contactData}
          navigation={navigation}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );

 const SecondRoute = () => (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <InvoiceDashboard
        navigation={navigation}
        index={index}
        customerId={route.params.id}
      />
    </View>
  );

  const ThirdRoute = () => (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Notes
        navigation={navigation}
        index={index}
        customerId={route.params.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

I am implementing React Native tab view with three tabs. If I enable lazy option the thirdroute is not rendering. If I disable lazy all the three tabs are rendering the UI but I am facing performance issue when loading data in all the tabs it's taking too much time.

I want to load data initially on first tab; later, if I change page, the second and third tab should load data. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.